# How to pull text from a span without a span title under a Class with BS4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I pull the text from the span without a span title?
The HTML snippet looks like this:

```
<div class="priceValue ">
  <span>$179.93</span>
</div>
```

My code now

```
s = requests.Session()

url="https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/solana/"


html = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, lxml)

div = soup.select_one('.priceValue span').text

print(div)
```

but that doesnt work, im pretty new to BS4 so that was kinda expected.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT (based on changes in question):

If there is only single element you do not have to iterate over an result set.

```
soup.select_one('.priceValue span').text
```

Take care that you quote your parser argument 'lxml' in `BeautifulSoup()`

#### Example

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
div = soup.select_one('.priceValue span').text

print(div)
```

#### Output (in moment of requesting)

```
$181.24
```